# How do I hide "MATLAB Command Window" when I run an m-file from command line?

Tags: windows, matlab, user-interface, command-line, command-prompt

I am running MATLAB with a command line string like this:

`C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('C:\<a long path here>\mfile.m');"`

The m-file contains a `plot()` function to plot a simple curve on the x-y plane.

The m-file successfully runs and draws the plotting with the command line string I specified above. However, every time I run this command, a window named "MATLAB Command Window" appears along with the plotting.

How do I make this "MATLAB Command Window" NOT appear, so that only the plotting will be visible.

The "MATLAB Command Window" looks like below:
[image]

Comment: If you produce a hidden figure (`h = figure('visibility','off');`) does it pop up?

Answer (score 3):

Great news!

With a bit of Java manipulation, it is possible! Start MATLAB **normally** (with the desktop etc.) Now run [setDesktopVisibility](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16330-setdesktopvisibility/)(false) and voila! E.g.

```
setDesktopVisibility(false);
mesh(rand(10));
pause;
setDesktopVisibility(true);
```

---

AFAIK you can't do it on Windows using the options with `matlab.exe`. If you really need to hide it, I'd recommend using the [MATLAB Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f29148.html) to display your figure. Additionally, if it's for simple things like plotting, etc. you could use [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) which works with M files and does not have a "Command Window" like MATLAB does (it runs in the Windows Command Prompt and hiding it is not that hard).

Answer (score 3):

If you are a running Matlab from another program on Windows, you can run it using the [Matlab COM Automation Server](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brd0v3w.html). The ActiveX control has a Visible property which will let you make the command window invisible, but looks like it leaves the plots visible.

Here's an example of how to do it using another Matlab as the controller.

```
ml = actxserver('Matlab.Application');
ml.Visible = false;
ml.Execute('surf(peaks)');
```

Or in VBScript.

```
Set ml = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")
ml.Visible = false
ml.Execute("surf(peaks)")
ml.Execute("pause(4)")
```

This interaction mode might be more what you want anyway, depending on how your workflow is structured, because it'll let you fire up the Matlab process once and make many plot requests on it, saving startup costs and letting you have multiple plots visible at once.

If you still want to call it from a command line, just run it through a .vbs wrapper script with the above VBScript code, but call `run('...\mfile.m')` instead of `surf(peaks)`. Your mfile.m will need some GUI logic that makes it block until the user dismisses the plot, replacing the `pause` call, so it doesn't disappear before they're done viewing it.

Comment: Andrew - I'm trying to contact you with a proposal, but I can't find your email anywhere. Can you please ping me at altmany at gmail dot com? - thanks

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
matlab -automation -wait -r "cd \'...\';..."
```

,which will show a minimized Window in the user session. By suggestion from Amro, we can send the minimized window to winlogin session locally so that we even cannot see the minimized Window:

```
psexec /i 0 matlab -nodesktop -wait -r "plot(rand(100,1)); print -dpng out.png;quit" >null 2>&1
```

,which will save the figure to C:\Windows\System32 silently (if ISD service is enabled it may pop up an interactive services detection dialog window, and /s or /x option do not work in Windows server 2003 or 2008.)

Comment: This does not address the issue; the command window will still open, only minimized

Comment: Or we can use Win32::OLE's ability to set visible=0 as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244413/can-win32ole-be-used-in-parallel-to-start-multiple-instance-of-matlab

Comment: yes, that's exactly what [AndrewJanke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6724142/97160) has shown in his solution above using COM automation (whether you use Perl, VB, or MATLAB itself to instantiate the COM server)

Comment: starting remotely will always hide the window and never be possible to make it visible: `PsExec.exe \\remoteserver -u user -p pass MATLAB.exe /wait /r "...;quit;"`

Comment: probably because the command window is opened on the remote machine (this is not like X11 forwarding on Unix)

Comment: No command window is opened on the remote machine, I have tried using send message or keys, or ROT methods, none of them can make it visible. Wondering maybe some debugger can get control of it by providing input command and get output of it for debugging purpose...

Comment: perhaps you need to specify: `psexec -i ...` to run interactive session, or `-x` to display it remotely. See the full list of switches [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Comment: Ok I just tried this locally and it works: `psexec -x matlab -nodesktop -wait -r "plot(rand(100,1)); print -dpng out.png; exit"`. No window will be visible. You should put this in your answer above :)

Comment: In fact the window is sent to the Winlogon desktop (the screen you see when no one is logged in). Read this blog post for more info: http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.com/2008/05/running-process-in-secure-winlogon.html

Comment: You are so resourceful! Using the -i with my session id in remote server and that blog method we can display window: `PsExec.exe /i 1 /s \\remoteserver cmd /c c:\Progra~1\Debugg~1\PsExec.exe /accepteula /i 1 /s MATLAB.exe /wait /r "enableservice('AutomationServer',true);try; cd '...';...catch;end;"`

Comment: thanks @Frank. I guess I was trying to do just the opposite in **NOT** showing the window on the local machine (no remotes involved). After all, this is what the above question is asking for... For posterity, do you mind editing your answer and explaining this stuff, and I'll upvote it :) This is definitely a useful method for hiding the command window

Comment: I tested in windows server 2003 and 2008, locally /i 0 will hide the window even in session 0. The /x or /s option do not work. Remotely only /i 0 /e or /e will work, the first will show window in session 0 the second will not. I aslo revised the answer for local machine according to your suggestion.

Comment: great +1. I only tested this on my local WinXP; The `/i 0` option will actually show the window in the current session, while `/x` option sends it to the Winlogon session hidden from the current user. Note that `/x` does not work for remote servers, only locally. I should mention that WinXP security model is much more relaxed as you know, so there is no UAC dialogs or anything like that, not sure about newer Windows versions though :)

Comment: ok according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me.aspx), starting with Vista things have changed a little bit, and session 0 is now isolated from users applications. It is now where all services run, while the user desktop run on session 1 upward.

Answer (score 1):

```
com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance.closeCommandWindow
```

You can probably use it from the command-line as:

```
-r "com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance.closeCommandWindow; run('C:\<a long path here>\mfile.m');"
```

Comment: It didn't make any difference.

Comment: @hk: I didn't try it from the command line, but from inside MatLab it definitely works on my system.  What version of MatLab are you using?

Comment: @BenVoigt: this closes the "Command Prompt" in the MATLAB IDE. The user is running MATLAB from the OS command line, and wishes to hide the MATLAB window that pop us. As far as I know, you can't...

Comment: The "-nodesktop" switch is probably conflicting with this, because the minimal Command Window there isn't the same as the one in the Desktop IDE, which MLDesktop controls. OP, try running it without "-nodesktop" and it may well work. The "-nodisplay" should probably be removed too, if you intend the plots to be visible; I think it's ignored on Windows, but it's superfluous and probably misleading since its purpose is to suppress graphics.