# Running a cmd file without GUI popping up

Tags: matlab, user-interface, command-line, terminal, cmd

I'm running a list of commands in a file:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash .............
xwin32 --session ....................
```

I would like to have them run without the GUI popping up in Windows and more of all I would like the command prompt GUI not to pop up, anyone have any idea how to do it? tnx

Comment: you cannot hide the MATLAB command window in MS Windows (well not without a hack: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6717688/97160)

Comment: @Amro cute :), how about the other gui?

Comment: As for running MATLAB in headless mode (dont show figures), you can use the `noFigureWindows` flag. Here is a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6776191/97160) where I explored the different command-line options and their impact

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do on Windows is:

#### batchScript.cmd

```
start /B /MIN matlab.exe -nodesktop -noFigureWindows -nosplash ^
    -r "surf(peaks); saveas(gcf, 'output.eps'); quit;"
```

You can add the `-wait` option if you need to process the results from MATLAB in a script (next command depends on output from previous one).