# Can Win32::OLE be used in parallel to start multiple instance of Matlab?

Tags: perl, matlab, parallel-processing, ole

When [`Parallel::Loops`](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aLoops) is combined with [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aOLE) to create multiple instance of Matlab, if we use

```
my $ML = Win32::OLE->new('Matlab.Application') or die "Cannot start MATLAB"
```

in each loop, the program crashes showing an unhandled exception.

If drop the `my` before `$ML` then it works, but at any time only one instance is running.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the benefit of creating multiple MATLAB COM servers in a parallel loop.

By default the server is created in shared mode, ie shared by all instances. The MATLAB engine is exposed to the user as single-threaded, so in your case all the clients computations are run in serial, not in parallel.

Fortunately you create MATLAB COM server in dedicated mode:

```
Win32::OLE->new('Matlab.Application.single')
```

See [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/specifying-a-shared-or-dedicated-server.html) for more info

PS: I know very little Perl :)

Comment: Win32::OLE->new('Matlab.Application.single') are tested working where we can start several instance of Matlab and send command to them to execute. Will check whether it still working in parallel loops.

Comment: I should point out that MATLAB has a product ([PCT toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/)) which adds a `parfor` construct to parellelize computation across multiple background workers, integrated into the language itself

Answer (score 0):

You really should show your full code.

If you are setting `my $ML` *inside* the anonymous subroutine passed to `Parallel::Loops` then you are setting the value in only a *child* process and the value will no be available to the parent.

It is unclear what you are using the `Matlab` processes for, but they will not persist after the death of their parent, which is one of the child processes that your main program starts.

You could try declaring `my @matlabs` outside the loop, and then doing

```
push @matlabs, Win32::OLE->new('Matlab.Application')
```

within the loop. But if you a number of *persistent* `Matlab` processes then why not just run a simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Parellel::Loop are tested not working with Win32::OLE to start multiple instance of Matlab,  but Parellel::Forkmanager works by using the "single" trick from Amro and clue from http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=894058 for an error of "CoInitialize has not been called":

before the loop use:

```
use Win32::OLE; # qw(EVENTS); #Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x800401f0: "CoInitialize has not been called"  
Win32::OLE->Initialize();
```

and inside the loop use:

```
my $ML = Win32::OLE->new('Matlab.Application.single') or die "Cannot start MATLAB";  
$ML->{'Visible'}=0;  
$ML->Execute('try;cd \''.$wkdir.'\';'.$executable.' '.$file.' '.$countfile.';catch;end;quit;');
```

The purpose of use  OLE instesd of just using:

```
system('matlab -automation -wait -r "try;cd \''.$wkdir.'\';'.$executable.' '.$file.' '.$countfile.';catch;end;quit;');
```

is to hide the Matlab window, we just want it to do the work but we get the honor. Using Perl to achieve the parallellized matlab parfor effects we can keep all the available CPU busy doing tasks allocated before the parellel loop and collect/combine the results after that loop.

Answer (score 0):

With further experiment, it is found that the error of Parallel::Loop and the error of *Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x800706be: "The remote procedure call failed* or *Free to wrong pool* when using Parellel::ForkManager can be both avoided by a suggestion from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21261292 and http://search.cpan.org/~gsar/libwin32-0.191/OLE/lib/Win32/OLE/TPJ.pod about silence the warning. All the code need to be included inside the parallel loop, and this are the working version:

```
    require Win32::OLE;
    import Win32::OLE;
    Win32::OLE->Initialize();
    no warnings qw(once); 
    $Win32::OLE::Warn = 0;
    my $ML = Win32::OLE->new('Matlab.Application.single') or die "Cannot start MATLAB";
    $ML->{'Visible'}=0;
    $ML->Execute('try;cd \''.$wkdir.'\';'.$executable.' '.$file.' '.$countfile.';catch;end;quit;');
```

Comment: The Win32::OLE can only lanch Matlab from local machine, remote invokation either not work or can only execute "quit" command. Distributed calculation through other Perl module like Gearman also failed.Even sysinternal PsExec failed with Matlab "-r" option. Only Python's RPyC tested so far can do really distributed calculation.

Comment: interesting experiment. I dont have any experience in this, but according to the docs, to use DCOM you need to specify the remote server in the input: http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm#Win32